# Plotly rangeslider with quarter dates

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I would like to draw plotly graphs with rangeslider (including start/end range), yet printing quarter dates on the X-axis, instead of the usual ymd format, as shown in the example below ; i.e. printing "Q1 2019" instead of "Jan 2019" :

```
library(plotly)
library(zoo)

d <- tibble::tibble(
  time = as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2020-08-31"), by = "quarters")),
  y = rnorm(seq_along(time))
)

d$time <- as.Date(d$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

plot_ly(d, x = ~time, y = ~y) %>%
  add_lines() %>%
  rangeslider(d$time[10], d$time[19])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `layout` using `ticktext` and `tickvals`. This is the code that will ensure you see years and quarters on the X-axis.

```
plot_ly(d, x = ~time, y = ~y) %>%
  add_lines() %>%
  rangeslider(d$time[10], d$time[19]) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(ticktext = paste0(c(rep(2018, 3), 
                                          rep(2019, 4), 
                                          rep(2020, 2)),
                                        " Q",
                                        c(2:4, 1)),
                      tickvals = d$time[10:18]
                      ))
```

Using `set.seed()` makes the code repeatable, (since you used `rnorm`). I used `set.seed(3958)` if you wanted to see the same output.

[image]

Another way that you can customize the text is through the zoom level. Plotly references [this site](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/tree/v2.2.3#locale_format) for the formatting here. There are a few examples on Plotly's website, as well. [Check it out](https://plotly.com/r/time-series/).

```
plot_ly(d, x = ~time, y = ~y) %>%
  add_lines() %>%
  rangeslider(d$time[10], d$time[19]) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(
    tickformatstops = list(
      list(dtickrange = list(NULL, "M1"),
           value = "%Y %b"),
      list(dtickrange = list("M1", "M6"),
           value = "%Y Q%q"),
      list(dtickrange = list("M6", NULL),
           value = "%Y Y")
    )))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to auto-adjust ticktext values showed when enlarging the rangeslider's range ?
i.e. showing only years instead of all ticktext values ? as it usually reacts with default date range.

Comment: I edited my answer with more info on formatting the axes.